# zomato api - unable to import into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json

How import the zomato api into Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 in order to create a database for restaurants?

Comment: There is brilliant documentation here: https://developers.zomato.com/documentation. Get an API key, write some code and come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: But my problem is that I don't understand how I can write it. How to connect this site to visual studio? And, what kind of page I need to open in visual studio

Comment: A simple google search turned this up: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1190592/A-few-great-ways-to-consume-RESTful-API-in-Csharp

Comment: You won't be connecting Zomato to Visual Studio. Visual Studio is your working environment. There you will write c# code to call the rest service. Read the article mxmissile is refering to, use RestSharp (I would) to get a response and use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate some data classes to hold the results.